# How to use an exported async function in cypress

Tags: javascript, async-await, cypress

I want to use a function that is written in a js separate file in my Cypress project.

I have a command in `support/commands.js` and I want to import a function from the`myfunc.js` file

```
    import { myfunc } from './myfunc.js'


    Cypress.Commands.add('login', (username, password, myimage) => {

    cy.visit('/Auth/Login')
    cy.get('input[id=username]').type(username)
    cy.get('input[id=password]').type(password, {sensitive: true})
    myfunc(myimage)
        .then((result) => {
            cy.log(result);
            cy.get('input[id=email]').type(result);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            cy.log('Error:', error);
        });
    cy.get('input[id=email]').type(result)
    });
```

And in `myfun.js`

```
    import Jimp from "jimp";
    
    
    export async function myfunc(imgpath, length = 5) {
        const image = await Jimp.read(imgpath);
        // some process to extract Email address from the image
        const result = Email;
        return result;
    });
```

when I run the *myfunc* from a node project it extracts the email address correctly. But when I want to run my Cypress command in a test it returns an error saying

> Error: TypeError: _jimp.default.read is not a function

I tried to import the jimp with `const Jimp = require('jimp');` but this time it returns another error

> Error: TypeError: Jimp.read is not a function